# How i take a first output before a command - Powershell

Tags: powershell

How do I take a first command output?
I Want to take the IdentifyingNumber.

I Have tried this following command:

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like "App"}
$getNumber = $app[1]

OutPut:
    IdentifyingNumber : {00000-00000-0000-000000000}
    Name              : App
    Vendor            : App 
    Version           : 1.0.0
    Caption           : App, Inc.
```

Comment: `$app[$index].IdentifyingNumber`

Comment: Thank's, this helped me so much @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically if you're putting [1] it selects the second object in the array as they start at [0] so if you wanted the first one do `$var = $app[0].IdentifyingNumber`

Comment: Thanks, how do I use this result $app[0].IdentifyingNumber on a var?

I Want to use IdentifyingNumber to call msiexec process.

Comment: @bmoreira18 Did you mean that you want to extract the `UninstallString` ?

Comment: @Hackoo No, I Want to print  `IdentifyingNumber : {00000-00000-0000-000000000}`

This app i'm triyng do uninstall need's to restart the computer to finish uninstallation, In my script i'm triyng to use IdentifiyngNumber to call msiexec.exe and use /norestart parameter.

Comment: If you go into the registry it'll have an entry with the uninstall string? then just tag that o restart flag? also just assign it to a variable?

Comment: Thank you @Isaac this argument opened my mind, stay safe ;)

Answer (score 1):

i have created this following scrip and it's worked so well, thank's for all, if i help someone this is the script.

```
$Keys = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

foreach ($subkey in $Keys) {

if($subkey.Name -notmatch "InstallWIX_"){

    Set-Location -Path $subkey.PSPath
    $app1 = Get-ItemProperty -Path ".\" | Where-Object displayname -Match "app1"
    $app2 = Get-ItemProperty -Path ".\" | Where-Object displayname -Match "app2"

    $GUID_APP1 = $app1.PSChildName
    $GUID_APP2 = $app2.PSChildName

    if ($app1.Displayname -eq "APP1") {
        & cmd /c msiexec.exe /x $GUID_APP1 /qn /norestart
    
    } elseif ($app2.Displayname -eq "APP2") {
        & cmd /c msiexec.exe /x $GUID_APP2 /qn /norestart
    
    }

}
}
```